# Changing a full last name to just the first letter of the name in R

Tags: r, stringr

I'm working in R. I have a dataset with people first and last names. There is a column called "First" and another column called "Last".

[image]

I want to change "Bodie" to just "B" and do the same for all the observations in the "Last" column.

I'm newer to programming so I don't even know where to start. I have looked at some of the string packages in R and can't quite figure out what to do. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `substr` to extract the first letter of the 'Last' column

```
df1$Last <- substr(df1$Last, 1, 1)
```

Or `sub` to remove all the characters other than the first

```
df1$Last <- sub("^(.).*", "\\1", df1$Last)
```

Or another option is to split the characters, select the first element

```
df1$Last <- sapply(strsplit(df1$Last, ""), `[`, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a variation on the @akrun answer which uses `sub` sans a capture group:

```
df1$Last <- sub("(?<=.).*$", "", df1$Last, perl=TRUE)
```